# Data Structure: Best and worst running time of an algorithm

Tags: performance, time, big-o, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm confused on which option is correct and why.So here are the questions:

1. What is the best-case running time of removing a node from the last position in a singly linked list.

   - (a)  O(1)
   - (b)  Ω(n)
   - (c)  O(log n)
   - (d)  Θ(n2)

   What I think:
   I think that the solution in b? because , I know that when you remove the last element of a linked list , it's O(n) since you have to traverse through all the elements of the linked list.
2. What is the worst case running time of pushing an element onto a stack implemented in a doubly-linked list?

   - (a)   O(1)
   - (b)   Q(8)
   - (c)   O(n log n)
   - (d)   Ω(n)

   What I think:
   I think that the solution is d, because the big Oh of inserting an element into the linked list is O(n) , where n is the number of elements you want to insert.

I'm really confused with this topic , if someone can modify my solution and understanding of why their solution is correct , then I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one you are right. In order to delete the last element you need to traverse the list and modify the pointer there so it is Ω(n).

In the second one however it is O(1). Stack is LIFO. You have a pointer to the head of the stack. All you need to do is to create a node for the new element, make it's next the current head and set the head to the newly created one. Therefore the number of operations is nota function of the size of the stack. It can be done in constant time which is O(1).

EDIT: The above answer assumes the data structure is not implemented with some array implementation which might again be O(n) due to resizing.

Comment: so the answer for 2 is a? or d?

Comment: Answer is D due to the the fact that it says a doubly link list. I apologize if my edit caused confusion but I believe it' better to be precise. Hope it helps.